# ipa crash log symbolication materializeForSet error

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, crash-reports, ipa

Recently I submitted ios app in appstore. The app was rejected. Apple gave me some crash log file. I tried to symbolicate those using atos command & found the following error:

**CheckOutVC.alergyView.materializeForSet (in My Project) (CheckOutVC.swift:23)**

on line 23 here is the code:

```
 @IBOutlet var alergyView: SquareBoxView!
```

Here CheckOutVC is my UIViewController & SquareBoxView is just a UIView. 
But what is materializeForSet? What should I have to change to get rid of this?

Comment: materializeForSet - it is related to coredata, google it once u get answer related to this

Comment: I didn't use core data in my project. I searched & found no trace of core data anywhere in my project.

Comment: then ask again once in apple

Answer (score 0):

I have googled the error.  I have found the same following explanation which says that an nil value has been found in an optional.

Considering that your `alergyView` is a outlet it is possible that you are accessing it at some point when it is nil.

My quess is that you might have forgotten to add `SquareBoxView` to your IB "subclass" label. I am guessing that it is still `UIView`.

Check access of the `alergyView` with `printf()`. You should find it to be nil somewhere.

Also check the connection when you highlight the text `alergyView`. It should show the `View` in `IB`. Check the `View` in `IB`. It may have multiple pointers. If it has it will work most of the time while crashing sometimes.

Comment: I checked this all before submitting my app. Everything's fine. No nil value, IBOutlet connection is ok. It works perfectly on my development device. But when I create ipa & install the app on different device the app crashes immediately after the launch.

Comment: I had a similar issue. The problem was that it only crashed on older devices. It was a animated gif. Can you test it on a second dev device?

Comment: actually my dev device is older. The device I'm installing ipa is latest than my development device. What did u do in your case to solve the problem?

Comment: It was a gif and couldn't work. I have reduced the image size but it didn't help. The processor and memory issues persisted. I told the customer that iPhone 5C and below just can't handle such a complex gif (animation). For the older devices I just used a splash screen (no complex animation). Take note that what ever you test IF you test if on the simulator it will take all the resources from your Mac (4 cores and up to 16GB of RAM) without crashing... a iPhone doesn't have those resources.

Comment: I'm testing from iphone 5 & my client has iphone 6. It works at my iphone 5 but the ipa not working on clients phone.